# Proof of the equivalence of validity of formula and its closure in a structure (Shoenfield's book)

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

Shoenfield's *Mathematical Logic* contains the following theorem and its corollary:

**Closure Theorem.** If ${\bf A}'$ is the closure of ${\bf A}$, then $\vdash {\bf A}'$ iff $\vdash {\bf A}$.

**Corollary.** If ${\bf A}'$ is the closure of ${\bf A}$, then ${\bf A}$ is valid in a structure ${\cal A}$ iff ${\bf A}'$ is valid in ${\cal A}$.

The proof of the corollary is presented as follows: Suppose that ${\bf A}$ is valid in ${\cal A}$. If $T$ has ${\bf A}$ as its only nonlogical axiom, then ${\cal A}$ is a model of $T$. By the closure theorem, $\vdash_T {\bf A}'$; so ${\bf A}'$ is valid in ${\cal A}$ by the validity theorem. The converse is proved similarly. $\square$

I can see intuitively that this is true, since the definition of validity in a structure is essentially asserting that the universally quantified version of ${\bf A}$ is valid (i.e. every instance of ${\bf A}$ is valid). Now, I don't completely understand why the case when ${\bf A}$ is the only nonlogical axiom of $T$ is sufficient for the proof. Note that at this point in the book, the Completeness Theorem is not yet proved and thus we can only infer that if a formula is a theorem, then it is valid (called the Validity Theorem in the book), but not the converse. Say that you had a theory $T$ with multiple nonlogical axioms or where ${\bf A}$ is not a theorem: how does the proof cover this case? Is it because the structure is applied to the language, rather than the theory itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking structure is applied to a language, model is applied to a theory as referenced [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#First-order_structures):

> The structure consists of a nonempty set D that forms the domain of discourse and an interpretation I of the non-logical terms of the signature... A first-order structure that satisfies all sentences in a given theory is said to be a model of the theory.

So if we have multiple nonlogical axioms $\bf A, B, C, \dots$ in $T$, the above proof holds since $\cal A$ can be always extended to be a model of $T$ satisfying all other axioms and sentences provided $T$ is consistent. The only possible issue is when $\bf A$ is neither a nonlogical axiom nor a theorem which is always correctly inferred from some axiom(s). But this seems impossible due to the specific definition of formula validity in this book mentioned on page 22:

> A formula is valid in $T$ if it is valid in every model of $T$; equivalently, if it is a logical consequence of the nonlogical axioms of $T$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought about it a bit, and I'm not sure I follow your reasoning. The definition of validity you quote refers to validity in a theory, while the theorem deals with validity in a structure (which might or might not be a model): IIUC, valid in a theory == valid in every model, and valid in a structure == every instance of the formula in that structure is valid. I think the idea is that since the structure applies to a language, the choice of a theory is irrelevant and thus we can always use an empty theory with just ${\bf A}$ as nonlogical axiom. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @ale64bit you're certainly correct now and described what I meant! Although here the author is talking about model of theory $T$ in above corollary proof, actually we should understand as a general structure without any attaching theory first (a theory should be really regarded as only maximally consistent closed formulas, not wffs with free variables). Some authors may even talk about structures without term variables valuation at all while a model will always have these valuation, so it's a bit confusing...

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. So the fact that it is a model is necessary to apply the validity theorem in the proof, but the choice of a specific theory is arbitrary, since the validity of the formula with respect to a specific structure doesn't change. Thanks for your help!